# Find a Closed Form for this Recursively Defined Sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, recursion

Let $\{a_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$ be defined by $a_{1} = 1$ and $a_{n} = \sqrt{1+a_{n-1}}$. The limit of this sequence can easily be determined to exist and subsequently found to be $\phi$ which is suprising to me. I don't see any intuition from the outset as to why this sequence would converge to this known constant. For fun, and for further understanding, I would like to try and find a closed form for this sequence. I am aware that there is a wealth of theory around recurrence relations that I do not have exposure to, so I suspect someone should be able to help with this.

Comment: Why is it surprising? $L=\sqrt{L+1}$ immediately gives $L^2=L+1$ which is exactly the polynomial which defines the golden ratio.

Comment: This is true, and once I arrived at that step in determining the limit it was clear. I guess I just didn't think about it in that way when I started playing with it.

Comment: I guess my intuition was more about the flavor of the sequence and less about the algebraic consequence of setting it equal to it's limit. I suppose you can ignore that sentence since it doesn't hinder the question, I only included it to motivate my curiosity.

Comment: I doubt that a closed form solution exists. Hoever, I think we can find an asymptotic approximation